# Passing shell result to another shell command?

Tags: macos, shell, automator

Just learning Automator here, but I'm trying to run a convert command on a file (blah.rtf->blah.mobi) and I'd like to take the resulting .mobi file and run another shell command on it in a different action. Either that, or is there a way to set it as a second variable and act on it in the same action?

Here's my code so far (using Calibre command-line tools):

First action:

```
for f in "$@"
do
    ebook-convert "$f" "$f".mobi
done
```

I'd like to pass that .mobi file to run:

```
for f in "$@"
do
    mv "$f" $(echo "$f" | cut -d'.' -f1).mobi
done
```

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Very closely related to (though marginally different from): [Using awk to remove one of multiple file extensions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479536/)

Comment: What are you having problems with? Your command is correct, and a plausible answer to the only question I could find here. (It would be more efficient to use a variable substitution, but that is tangential to your main question. `mv "$f" "${f%.*}".mobi`)

Comment: Oh, you certainly can do as much as you want inside the first `for` loop, and indeed probably should.

Comment: There's some problems in Automator passing that modified .mobi file into the next shell command. I can't get it to rename it, and instead I get an Automator error. My guess is that it's not passing any file into the second shell command, so the reference to $@ and $f is useless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to pass the converted files to subsequent actions, the first action must output their paths:

```
for f in "$@"
do
    ebook-convert "$f" "$f".mobi
    echo "$f".mobi
done
```

But you can make it much simpler by making the first action create the files with the correct names in the first place (as @tripleee suggested):

```
for f in "$@"
do
    ebook-convert "$f" "${f%.*}".mobi
    # echo "${f%.*}".mobi  # optional -- uncomment if you need to pass the files on to subsequent actions
done
```